# How to store Object Types in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I'm new to using Room on Android & I have a difficulty. I have a class named "Employee" with String name and Object EmployeeType which has it's attributes. I need to represent both in Room entity table, also to check for nulls as they could be null.

```
data class Employee(

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("employee_type")
    val employeeType: EmployeeType? = null,
)

data class EmployeeType(

    @field:SerializedName("full_staff")
    val fullStaff: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("contract_staff")
    val contractStaff: String? = null 
)

@Entity
class EmployeeTable (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String

    //.. represent EmployeeType here for both full_staff and contract_staff
    //.. also EmployeeTypes could be null, how do I handle null pointers
)


// My DOA

@Dao
interface EmployeeTableDao {
    @Query("select * from EmployeeTable order by id DESC")
    fun findAll(): LiveData<List<EmployeeTable>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(employeeTable: List<EmployeeTable>)
}

// API sample

    {
        "staff": [
            {
                "name": "Jeff",
                "employee_type": {
                    "full_staff": "No",
                    "contract_staff": "Yes"
                }
            },
            //...
       ],
    }
```

Please how do I achieve this?

Comment: Use relations, most likely: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, but Embedded doesn't work. Error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.

Comment: Do you want to store employee type in another table?

Comment: "Thanks, but Embedded doesn't work" -- there are multiple techniques on that Web page. "Error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor" -- you might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] for that problem along with the full error message.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare I finally resulted to creating a json converter and that worked fine.

Comment: @NatarajKR No, I want to store employee type in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

For storing employee data in the same table and later to access the same in Kotlin, create a variable of type `EmployeeType` in `EmployeeTable` entity class and create a **TypeConvertor** and register it to the Database class. The **TypeConvertor** will convert the `EmployeeType` to `JSON` string using *GSON* to store in DB and back to `EmployeeType` when accessed from DB.

```
@Entity
class EmployeeTable (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String

    @ColumnInfo(name = "employee_type")
    val emmployeeType: EmployeeType
)
```

---

### Convertor class

```
class EmployeeTypeConvertor {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromEmployeeType(employeeType: EmployeeType): String {
        return /* JSON string using GSON or something */
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toEmployeeType(employeeType: String): EmployeeType {
        return /* EmployeeType from JSON string using GSON or something */
    }
}
```

Comment: I already said I created a Converter in my comments though, solved the problem